# DLNA server outside LAN

Tags: dlna, upnp

I have a Sony Bravia HDTV that automatically detects my NAS as a media server, enabling playback of video files. However, is it possible for a remote server running windows with external static IP to act as DLNA media server for my home network? Any other method for playing remote video files on my HDTV would work too.

Comment: Nope. DLNA is only designed to work on a LAN, not over the internet. There are other solutions to view video over the internet with a TV but not via the DLNA-protocol. If those other methods work with your TV...? We don't know because you didn't specify the model of your TV. If it can run Apps you could look at Plex.

Comment: Not directly.  Maybe if you could VPN into it you might be able to get it to work.  Plex is ok.  Low bandwidth could make it impractical to stream media also.